# for loop using enumerate terminates unexpectedly

Tags: python, for-loop, enumerate

Here is a simple for loop through an enumerate object. This terminates due to (this line I have mentioned as a comment). Why is that?

```
enum_arr = enumerate(arr)
for ele in enum_arr:
    print(ele)
    print(list(enum_arr)[ele[0]:]) # terminates due to this line
```

Output:

```
(0, 0)
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)]
```

If I comment out the second print statement, then:

Output:

```
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
(3, 3)
(4, 4)
(5, 5)
```

As expected.
Why is this happening?

Comment: `enumerate()` is an *iterator*. It can only be looped over once. `list()` loops over the iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enumerate()` gives you an [*iterator* object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator). Iterators are like a bookmark in a book that can only be moved forward; once you reach the end of the book you can't go back anymore, and have to make a new bookmark.

You then use that iterator in two places; the `for` loop and `list()`. The `list()` function moved the bookmark all the way to the end, so the `for` loop can't move it any further.

You'd have to create a *new* `enumerate()` object in the loop if you want to use a separate, independent iterator:

```
enum_arr = enumerate(arr)
for ele in enum_arr:
    print(ele)
    print(list(enumerate(arr[ele[0]:], ele[0])))
```

This does require that `arr` is itself *not* an iterator, it has to be a sequence so you can index into it. I'm assuming here that you have a list, tuple, range or similar value.

Note that I passed in `ele[0]` twice, the second argument to `enumerate()` lets you set the start value of the counter.

It is easier to use a tuple assignment here to separate out the count and value:

```
for count, value in enum_arr:
    print((count, value))
    print(list(enumerate(arr[count:], count)))
```

Demo:

```
>>> arr = range(6)
>>> enum_arr = enumerate(arr)
>>> for count, value in enum_arr:
...     print((count, value))
...     print(list(enumerate(arr[count:], count)))
...
(0, 0)
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)]
(1, 1)
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)]
(2, 2)
[(2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)]
(3, 3)
[(3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)]
(4, 4)
[(4, 4), (5, 5)]
(5, 5)
[(5, 5)]
```

Coming back to the book analogy, and the requirement that `arr` is a *sequence*: as long as `arr` is a book with page numbers, you can add more bookmarks at any point. If it is some other [iterable type](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable), then you can't index into it and so would have to find some other means to 'skip ahead' and back again. Stretching the analogy further: say the book is being *streamed* to you, one page at a time, then you can't go back once you received all the pages. The solution coud be to create a local cache of pages first; if you can spare the memory that could be done with `cached_copy = list(arr)`. Just take into account that you have to be sure that the book you are receiving is not so long as to require more space than you actually have. And some iterables are endless, so would require infinite memory!

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. You answered very well and quick.